# Developing a web service and consumer at same time

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, service-reference

Using Visual Studio 2010 professional I'm creating a WCF web service and a MVC 3 web site that will consume that web service.

How would I reasonably go around doing that. Should I keep them as seperate projects in the same solution? Can I skip referencing and running the service locally while developing, just use it like a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are doing this on a daily basis like this:

- Create single solution
- Add a class library project and create your web service interface
- Add a WCF service library project and create a service implementation for your interface (ref your service interface project)
- Add a MVC3 web application project and reference your service interface project here also
- In your MVC3 web application project add either a direct reference to the service implementation (during development, use it like a library) or add a service reference to your WCF service library (for running as a seperate webserver in production).

This gives a fast development cycle, and if you stick to the interface operations, also the possibility to deploy the WCF service as a separate entity when you need to go into production, or scale out.

Comment: Do you define the DataContracts in the ServiceLibrary or the same library as the Interface?

Comment: DataContracts are definately interface assets. So they go into the interface project.